# Finding Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions of a Sturm-Liouville Problem (SOLVED)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I need to find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions of the following differential equation: $$y'' = -sy, \;\;\;\;y(0)=2y'(0), \; y'(1)=0.$$

I've already found the eigenvalues of the function. If $s>0$, then $$y(x) = A\cos(\sqrt sx) + B \sin(\sqrt s x)$$ $$y'(x) = -\sqrt s A \sin(\sqrt s x) + \sqrt sB\cos(\sqrt sx).$$

If we plug in our boundary conditions, we get $$\left.\begin{align}A - 2\sqrt 2 B &= 0 \\ -\sqrt{s}A\sin(\sqrt s) + \sqrt{s}B\cos(\sqrt{s}) & = 0.\end{align}\right\}$$

To solve the eigenvalue problem, I want to avoid the trivial solution of $A=B=0$. In order to accomplish that, I decided to find where there will be more than one solution. So I set the determinant of the coefficient matrix equal to $0$, like so:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1 &- 2\sqrt s \\ -\sin(\sqrt s) & \cos(\sqrt s)\end{vmatrix}  = \cos (\sqrt s) - 2\sqrt s \sin(\sqrt s) = 0.$$ Thus, I get eigenvalues $s$ as the solution to the equation $$2\sin(\sqrt s) = \frac{\cos(\sqrt s)}{\sqrt s}.$$

Here's the part I'm stuck at: I need to find the eigenfunction associated with the eigenvalue $s$. I initially tried solving the above equation for $\sqrt s$ and substitute it into $y(x)$, but my answer did not end up correct. I've also tried rearranging the equation to be $\tan(\sqrt s) = \frac{1/2}{\sqrt s}$, and [attempted to matched it up with the outline found here, but it still wasn't coming out right](http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse35.html). Can anyone provide any pointers on how to find the eigenfunction associated with the eigenvalue $s$?

EDIT:

Comment: What is your question? I see (Solved) in the title, but no solution.